# PouchDB fails to sync on iOS 9 - iPhone 5S

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I am developing an app with IONIC and PouchDB. The app perfectly synchronizes with remote CouchDB and works perfectly well on Android. But the PouchDB fails to sync on iOS.

I am testing on iOS 9 and iPhone 5S.

What could be going wrong with the code in iOS ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using WKWebView? PouchDB does not support WKWebView, unless you use the FruitDOWN adapter: http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser