# PouchDB replicate going to 'Pause' block on iOS 9

Tags: android, ios, couchdb, pouchdb

While developing an Ionic CouchDb-PouchDb application - I am trying to replicate the remote database as soon as the user logs in. My code looks like :

```
PouchDB.replicate(remote_db, local_db, {
            live: true,
            retry: true
        }).on('change', function (info) {
            // handle change
        }).on('paused', function () {
            // replication paused (e.g. user went offline)            
        }).on('active', function () {
            // replicate resumed (e.g. user went back online)
        }).on('denied', function (info) {
            // a document failed to replicate, e.g. due to permissions
        }).on('complete', function (info) {
            // handle complete
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            // handle error
        });
```

Each time the replicate function is invoked - it is going into the '`paused`' block even if the connection was **NOT interrupted**.

What is going wrong?

I have used **FruitDOWN adapter** as suggested by Nolan Lawson in my previous question ([PouchDB fails to sync on iOS 9 - iPhone 5S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293323/pouchdb-fails-to-sync-on-ios-9-iphone-5s))

However the same code - works perfectly on Android and it enters the '`complete`' block.

Comment: Without seeing your full code or the error message, it's hard to tell. My guess is that it's a misconfigured CORS on the server, which you could tell by looking at the Network tab and seeing if any requests to the remote server are passing (or doing remoteDB.info() to check). If not, could you file a bug with full steps to reproduce? FruitDOWN is passing our test suite on iOS, so we're not aware of any issues with replication.

Comment: Also another option is to downgrade from WKWebView to UIWebView, which is frankly more stable and faster due to having WebSQL. WKWebView does not have WebSQL exposed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137760

Comment: Thanks Nolan.. I am really grateful for your support. As regards the network tab.. I can not do that as I am testing on i Phone 5 using **Ionic View** .. so its a app like feeling. As regards downgrading to UIWebView .. I will give it a try. But this is causing on iOS only ..while Android is working like a charm

Comment: Also- is the iOS preventing the PouchDB to store data on the device ?? Could this be a bug ?? or issue ?? @nlawson